# Less global variable and mixin usage in media-queries

Tags: less, media-queries, scope

I've got a problem when using global varibale in a mixin which is used in @media-query.
Point is in different @media-query the variable is rewrited. So I would like the mixin to use updated value but it doesnt seem to do it.

Here's whats bugging me:

```
@base-font-size: 18px;
@modifier: 7;

// font size for elements that are not headings
// if I pass "clean" as second arg then the line-height will be same as font size
// dont focus on it - @modifier is the problem

.font(@size, @line-height) when (@line-height = clean) {
  font-size: @size;
  line-height: @size;
}

.font(@size, @line-height: true) when not (@line-height = clean) {
  font-size: @size;
  line-height: unit((@size + @modifier), px);
}

body {
  .font(@base-font-size);
}



@media (max-width: 800px) {
  @base-font-size: 18px;
  @modifier: 5;

  body {
    .font(@base-font-size);
    color: red;
  }
}
```

It compiles into:

```
body {
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 25px;
}
@media (max-width: 800px) {
  body {
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 25px;
    color: red;
  }
}
```

The @modifier value in @media has changed.
If I would like to use it in @media like this: line-height: @modifier+@base-font-size then the new value would be used and everything is ok.

But when I want to use this new value in a mixin and use this mixin in @media - then this mixin is using old value(7) not the new one(5).

Could anyone please advice where I made my mistake and if's a less bug (1.3.3) how can change my mixin to avoid it?

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this.

I needed to define one more var: @media and vary my mixins so that they will or wont be used in particular cases.

@media: desktop;

```
@base-font-size: 10px;
@mod-desktop: 10;
@mod-mobile: 1px;

.font(@size, @line-height) when (@line-height = clean) and (@media = desktop) {
  font-size: @size;
  line-height: @size;
}

.font(@size, @line-height: true) when not (@line-height = clean) and (@media = desktop) {
  @mod: @mod-desktop;
  font-size: @size;
  line-height: unit((@size + @mod-desktop), px);
}

.font(@size, @line-height) when (@line-height = clean) and (@media = mobile) {
  font-size: @size;
  line-height: @size;
}

.font(@size, @line-height: true) when not (@line-height = clean) and (@media = mobile) {
  @mod: @mod-mobile;
  font-size: @size;
  line-height: unit((@size + @mod-mobile), px);
}


body {
  .font(@base-font-size); // this will use font-size from top of the file
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
  @media: mobile;
  @base-font-size: 5px;

  body {
    // this will use the font-size from @media scope and mixin for mobile will be called
    .font(@base-font-size); 
  }
}
```